# Hosting two WCF services using a single console app

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to host two services using a single console app. However, when I am trying to do so, only one service gets hosted, while the other does not.

Program.cs:

```
namespace WWWCFHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WWWCF.Login)))
            {
                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service1 Started");
            }
            using (ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(WWWCF.UserRegistration)))
            {
                host1.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Service2 Started");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="WWWCF.Login" behaviorConfiguration="WWWCF.mexBehaviour1">
        <endpoint address="Login" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WWWCF.ILogin">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service name="WWWCF.UserRegistration" behaviorConfiguration="WWWCF.mexBehaviour2">
        <endpoint address="UserRegistration" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WWWCF.IUserRegistration">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8090"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WWWCF.mexBehaviour1">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WWWCF.mexBehaviour2">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

As in the code above, I am trying to host one service on port 8080 and the other on port 8090. When I run the application, the first service starts and then closed automatically and the second service remains started.  How can I host both the services simultaneously ?

I have gone through the link : [Two WCF services, hosted in one console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187308/two-wcf-services-hosted-in-one-console-application)

I have gone through other threads as well.But they do not solve my issue.

Will be happy to provide any further details if required.

Comment: As soon as you leave the `using` statement, your scope for your service is gone.

Comment: Even if I don't use 'using' statement, the same thing happens.

Comment: Thanks everyone for looking into it.

Comment: Hi guys. I am again struck. Editing the post.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer on this question, you'll get more response if you create a new question.

Comment: Oh is it? I just thought that the entire details are there in this question. So it would be easy to answer this way.

Comment: Ya, that is another question.  Just phrase it in the context of your client.  You can reference this question to give detail on how its hosted, but your client is a different question.  Plus, no one gets notified that you've edited your question.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. Will do that.

Comment: I have asked another question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997204/consuming-multiple-wcf-services-from-a-single-mvc-client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first service jumps out of the `using` block and so is disposing too early. Try this...

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WWWCF.Login)))
using (ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(WWWCF.UserRegistration)))
{
     host.Open();
     Console.WriteLine("Service1 Started");

     host1.Open();
     Console.WriteLine("Service2 Started");
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: This solves my issue. With this solution I can host as many services as I want easily. 
Thanks so much.

Comment: You could, but be aware of memory consumption. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Keep in mind, if you are hosting "100s of services" via this console app, they are all on one thread, and will block each other.

Comment: @CamBruce Also true. This would be a bitch to debug!

Comment: I will not have 100s of services. That was just a what-if scenario.:) Still, if I did have 100s of services, would you have any particular approach to suggest?

Comment: Oh. Is there no better way to handle the situation? Even using IIS hosting? Coz console app will not be used in live scenario.

Answer (score 5):

You're instantly closing the first, since it's in the using.  You need to set it up so the first using scope doesn't end until after the `ReadLine()` call.

Try:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WWWCF.Login)))
{
     host.Open();
     Console.WriteLine("Service1 Started");

     using (ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(WWWCF.UserRegistration)))
     {
            host1.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service2 Started");
            Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: This solves my issue. Thanks. But I was wondering what would I do if I had a lot more than 2 services(say 100) to host. Nesting **using** inside another will increase nesting levels to 100s. The solution mentioned by @simonlchilds will be better off in such a case.

Comment: @AnkitMittal That solution is identical to this one - the only difference is syntax used (I didn't do it his way, as it changes the behavior in the case of exceptions - this, and yours, doesn't instantiate the second service if the first throws on open).

Comment: If you have 100's of services, you can just keep a collection of the references to each service, then after `Console.ReadLine()` loop through and `Dispose()` of them all.

Comment: @CamBruce That being said, if you have *hundreds* of self hosted services, I'd rethink your overall design, and really question why they're in the same console app...

Comment: In live scenario, I wouldn't be using a Console app though. @Cam - Yes. Disposing must be taken care of. I will do that.

Comment: @ReedCopsey regarding exception handling... I agree with you, maybe a better solution would be to avoid using `using` blocks and ensure the `Dispose()` was called on all non null host instances inside a `finally` block. That being said, this whole design is a bit funky!